# Make the pipe end follow an arc

Tags: modeling

I would like the end of the pipe to form an approximate 270deg arc, as sketched, rather that the parabola as it is now:

[image: screenshot]

I have no idea, which deform to use.

It is going to be dust-vacuuming pipe, the dust source a bit below the centre of the blue arc. As of the final shape, it is not precisely determined as far as it works well. In any case, the object should be bounded with two parallel planes from the top and from the bottom, as it is now, and the blue sketch lies on the bottom plane.

The pipe's profile should change, from top to bottom, somewhat like that:
[image: sketch]

Model source: [image]

Comment: do you have a picture of the final object you want?

Comment: @moonboots I don't, there is some arbitrariness, but I added a more precise description of what I want to the question.

Comment: maybe show some pictures, it's hard to interpolate what a 2D curve could give in 3D. Also, do you have any reason to use a Mesh Deform modifier?

Comment: @moonboots no, in fact the Mesh Deform gave me a parabola which I do not want. I added an image with a series of desired profiles of the pipe.

Comment: @moonboots no, it should be a pipe similar to what is now, but its bottom exit should surround more a vertical axis, not a horizontal one.

Comment: too hard to visualise but maybe someone will understand  ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whichever shape you want the nozzle, it's probably better to loft it than to deform it. Make a series of profiles with the same number of vertices, use 'Bridge Edge Loops', adjusting its options, (Number of cuts, Profile, Smoothness, etc)...

[image]

... and then you can use modifiers to Solidify, Bevel, and Subdivide the geometry.